# Peskin and Schroeder equation 3.136 (book edition 1995)

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, textbook-erratum

I'm studying Peskin and Schroeder's QFT and I'm confused by equation 3.136 on page 68:

[image]

$\textbf{Previously, on page 48, equation 3.62 says:}$

[image]

$\textbf{My question is: how do we deduce 3.136 from 3.62?}$ $\textbf{It doesn't seem to me that} \boldsymbol{\xi^s}\textbf{ and }\boldsymbol{\eta^s}\textbf{ are related to each other?}$

Comment: Greetings! Please see [this guidance on screenshots of text](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126) (summary: avoid screenshots of text).

Answer (score 0):

You must have an old edition. In my edition (3.136)has the $\sigma$ as well. Also, $\xi$ and $\eta$ are arbitrary spinors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest version! In the latest version book, equation (3.62) is the spinor solution belongs to negative energy electrons, and (3.136) is belongs to positive energy positron. If you still don't understand then try to interpret it with Dirac sea level (particle-hole transformation), then you will see (3.62) and (3.136) are physical equivalent. And BTW, (3.62) and (3.136) hold same orthogonality relation & completeness relation.